# Matching columns values between two DataFrames of the same structure

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to match up two DataFrames and generate a new DataFrame showing whether column values Match or Not.

**DF1** has a Title/Name column, then all subsequent columns represent a different attribute, which I've just named ATT1, ATT2, etc for now.

**DF2** follows the same structure as DF1.

I want my **Output DF** to be the same structure, but instead of values for each of the attribute I want it to tell whether the value for each attribute matched between DF1 and DF2 (denoted by "**M**") or did not match (denoted by "**NM**").

Note:
In the example below, if an attribute is in DF2 by not in DF1, this just isn't included in the Output DF. Although it would also be okay for this to be included, but just with the values left blank or something like "ATT in DF2 but not in DF1". However, this is not too important.

Also it shouldn't ever be the case that an attribute is in DF1 that isn't also in DF2.

I'm struggling to get started with this, so any help appreciated. I think some kind of **merge** but I'm not sure.

**DF1**

| TITLE | ATT1 | ATT2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | A | G |
| Karen | B | JK |
| John | D | H |

**DF2**

| NAME | ATT1 | ATT2 | ATT3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | A | G | W |
| John | D | H | E |
| Karen | F | JK | EE |
| Aaron | F | BB | E |

**Output DF**

| Name | ATT1 | ATT2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | M | M |
| John | M | M |
| Karen | NM | M |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a vectorial approach, use index alignment:

```
out = (df1
 .set_index('TITLE')
 .eq(df2.set_index('NAME'))
 .reindex(df1['TITLE'], fill_value=False)
 .replace({True: 'M', False: 'NM'})
 .reset_index()[df1.columns]
 )
```

Output:

```
   TITLE ATT1 ATT2
0   Mike    M    M
1  Karen   NM    M
2   John    M    M
```

Comment: Thank you. Seems like the simplest solution. I'm just wondering, is there any way for it to ignore certain values? For example, if any value (in either dataframe) was equal to "n/a" - just have "n/a" show in the final report, rather than M or NM

Comment: @TheDataPanda then I'd suggest to use a mask to post-process the output to restore those values. Something like `.mask(df1.isin(['n/a']), df1)`

Answer (score 0):

**Important Part:**

```
for col in df2.columns:
    if col in df1.columns:
        output_df[col] = ['M' if name in df1.index and df1.loc[name, col] == df2.loc[name, col] else 'NM' for name in df2.index]
    else:
        output_df[col] = 'NM'
```

**Testing:**

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'TITLE': ['Mike', 'Karen', 'John'],
         'ATT1': ['A', 'B', 'D'],
         'ATT2': ['G', 'JK', 'H']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'NAME': ['Mike', 'John', 'Karen', 'Aaron'],
         'ATT1': ['A', 'D', 'F', 'F'],
         'ATT2': ['G', 'H', 'JK', 'BB'],
         'ATT3': ['W', 'E', 'EE', 'E']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df1.set_index('TITLE', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('NAME', inplace=True)

output_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df2.index)

for col in df2.columns:
    if col in df1.columns:
        output_df[col] = ['M' if name in df1.index and df1.loc[name, col] == df2.loc[name, col] else 'NM' for name in df2.index]
    else:
        output_df[col] = 'NM'

output_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(df1)
print("------")
print(df2)
print("------")
print(output_df)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I do seem to get this error when I run it on my actual dataframes: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`. Can't see why I would be getting the example I gave you is just a simplified version of them.

Comment: pls have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o. Simplified one is working,  but maybe u have to update in your own code this part: ['M' if name in df1.index and df1.loc[name, col] == df2.loc[name, col] else 'NM' for name in df2.index]